# repair lost chains after wrong chkdsk usage

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card, chkdsk

I made a big mistake during using chkdsk. During running 
chkdsk /f /r on an SD memory card through usb I was asked

```
Convert lost chains to files (Y/N)?
```

As I was in a hurry I mistakenly answered `N`. I wanted to answer `Y` to get the *.chk files generated from the lost chains.

The SD Card contained information of an avi video that was crashed during saving. Is there any possibility to get the *.chk files or the content of the former lost chain?

I would be great if you can give me advice what can I do now.

Kind regards,

Roland

Comment: Honestly, I have never responded "No" to that error to know what happens. So, you need to run the CHKDSK again and see if it finds the lost chains again. If it didn't, it means it has discarded the lost chains.

Comment: Yes, I ran chkdsk with the same /f /r again but it did not find anything again. So it has discarded the lost chains :( What can I do now? (I have never entered "n" before, too but as I was in a hurry and in the hope I can do it later when I have more time ...)

Comment: Maybe I wrote it unclear. I only did the "n" answer once. The second time chkdsk didn't ask me because me. So I cannot answer "y" the socond time. Is there a way to get the discarded chains back now?

Comment: You can try downloading and running Recuva but I am afraid I don't believe you will get any results. I regret to inform you that unfortunately, you must prepare yourself for the worst outcome.

Comment: Thank you very much. At least it found two pieces of the video file and I will see if I can recover it. Recuva was really a great advice :)

Answer (score 1):

A decent file carver might be able to get yours out of your predicament. Chkdsk has modified the file system, so the directory and FAT entries cannot be used. This is why conventional file recovery and undelete software probably will not work.

---

**Problem 2**
: Fragmentation

If files are fragmented then 99 out 100 carvers will give you corrupt files. They can not put the file fragments together.

JPEG Recovery LAB is a tool that can piece image files together and I think it does AVIs too.